# I am getting error because of "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, arrays

```
Row1=['⬜','⬜','⬜']
Row2=['⬜','⬜','⬜']
Row3=['⬜','⬜','⬜']
Rows=[Row1,Row2,Row3]
print(Row1)
print(Row2)
print(Row3)
num=input("enter your position in form(RowColumn):")
Rows[int(num[0]),int(num[1])]="X"
print(Row1)
print(Row2)
print(Row3)
```

^^^
The above is my code. I tried to create a map and put X on position which user types.

I am getting error becuase of "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Comment: You've got a list of list. You need to index it accordingly, i.e `Rows[int(num[0])]` to select a row, and then `[int(num[1])]` to select an element of this row.

Comment: so my ninth line should be like this: Rows[[int(num[0])],[int(num[1])]]="X" , right?

Comment: No. `Rows[0]` is the same as `Row1`, right? And if you wanted to access first element of `Row1`, you'd do `Row1[0]`, right? So why are you combining that into `Rows[0, 0]`, not `Rows[0][0]`?